# What kind of database is Cassandra DB?

Tags: nosql, cassandra

I was taking some courses to understand better the way Cassandra works (at academy.datastax.com) and by what I gathered it came to me that it is a Key Value Database because of the way it stores data based on a hash of the key and distributes to nodes accordingly. But everywhere I look people say Cassandra is a Column-Based Database and I can't see why.

Answer (score 1):

From [wiki.apache.org](http://wiki.apache.org/):

> Cassandra is a partitioned row store, where rows are organized into tables with a required primary key. The first component of a table's primary key is the partition key; within a partition, rows are clustered by the remaining columns of the PK. Other columns may be indexed independent of the PK. This allows pervasive renormalization to "pre-build" result sets at update time, rather than doing expensive joins across the cluster.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/8783

---

"a partitioned row store" a.k.a. a column-oriented data store. Note it is not a true "Column-store". It is column-oriented or a column-family store. The terminology of partitioned row store versus column-oriented is less important than understanding what was shared though. If you walk into Cassandra thinking it is a true column store, you'll be surprised. – https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/55511